# SSIS package execution (truncate table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have SSIS package which truncate the table data and insert the records. What happen if some program reads the data from the table at the time of truncating table data

Answer (score 0):

For truncate operations, SQL Server will acquire a schema modification (Sch-M) lock which prevents all operations on that table until the lock is released. So in other words, during the truncate operation, no other process will be able to read or write to the table.